# getting "oauth_signature does not match expected value" error while authenticating tumblr

Tags: java, api, oauth, tumblr

I got request token (oauth_token and oauth_token_secret) using https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/request_token this URL.
Then I constructed authorize URL using oauth_token which I got in the previous step. 
When I try to get access token using my app consumerKey, consumerSecret, and oauth_token , oauth_token_secret, getting 
"oauth_signature does not match expected value" error message.

Message constructed for HmacSHA1,

```
String signatureBaseString = "GET&" + URLEncoder.encode(accessURL, "UTF-8") + "&" + "oauth_callback%3D" + URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.encode(redirectUrl, "UTF-8"), "UTF-8") + "%26oauth_consumer_key%3D" + URLEncoder.encode(consumerKey, "UTF-8") + "%26oauth_nonce%3D" + URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(millis), "UTF-8") + "%26oauth_signature_method%3D" + URLEncoder.encode("HMAC-SHA1", "UTF-8") + "%26oauth_token%3D" + URLEncoder.encode(oauthToken, "UTF-8") + "%26oauth_timestamp%3D" + URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(time), "UTF-8") + "%26oauth_token_secret%3D" + URLEncoder.encode(oauthTokenSecret, "UTF-8") + "%26oauth_version%3D" + URLEncoder.encode("1.0", "UTF-8") + "%oauth_verifier%3D" + verifier;
```

Header constructed to get access token using request token,

```
String accessHeader = "OAuth " + "oauth_callback=\"" + URLEncoder.encode(redirectUrl, "UTF-8") + "\"" + ", oauth_consumer_key=\"" + URLEncoder.encode(consumerKey, "UTF-8") + "\"" + ", oauth_nonce=\"" + URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(millis), "UTF-8") + "\"" + ", oauth_signature=\"" + URLEncoder.encode(signature, "UTF-8") + "\"" + ", oauth_signature_method=\"" + URLEncoder.encode("HMAC-SHA1", "UTF-8") + "\"" + ",oauth_token=\"" + URLEncoder.encode(oauthToken, "UTF-8") + "\"" + ", oauth_timestamp=\"" + URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(time), "UTF-8") + ",oauth_token_secret=\"" + URLEncoder.encode(oauthTokenSecret, "UTF-8") + "\"" + ", oauth_version=\"" + URLEncoder.encode("1.0", "UTF-8") + "\"" + ", oauth_verifier=\"" + verifier + "\"";
```

Can anyone please help me to solve this?